# Java - Fade between images in Synth

Tags: java, image, fade, look-and-feel, synth

For a class assignment, I have to PERFECTLY replicate the windows 7 calculator in java. Currently, I am working on the button hover. The problem I am having is that the windows calculator fades between the default and hover state (as well as the pressed state). I want to know if it is possible to make it so Java will fade between my two states.

I currently have the following Synth code.

```
<synth>
    <!-- Style that all regions will use -->
    <style id="backingStyle">
        <!-- Make all the regions opaque-->
        <opaque value="TRUE"/>
        <font name="Dialog" size="12"/>
        <state>
            <!-- Provide default colors -->
            <color value="#D8D987" type="BACKGROUND"/>
            <color value="RED" type="FOREGROUND"/>
        </state>
    </style>
    <bind style="backingStyle" type="region" key=".*"/>
    <style id="buttonStyle">
        <!-- Shift the text one pixel when pressed -->
        <insets top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0"/>
        <state>
            <imagePainter method="buttonBackground" path="images/button.png" sourceInsets="10 10 10 10"/>
        </state>
        <state value="MOUSE_OVER">
            <imagePainter method="buttonBackground" path="images/button_hover.png" sourceInsets="10 10 10 10"/>
        </state>
        <state value="PRESSED and MOUSE_OVER">
            <imagePainter method="buttonBackground" path="images/button_pressed.png" sourceInsets="10 10 10 10"/>
        </state>
    </style>
    <!-- Bind buttonStyle to all JButtons -->
    <bind style="buttonStyle" type="region" key="Button"/> 
</synth>
```

I found an example that only works in Java 5 that quickly cycles between 6-8 images to make it look like its fading. Something like that would also work for me.

If you need anything that I didn't post, you can get it all [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/5e5qba0djlmogm8/Calculator.zip)

Thanks in advance.